# What is the appropriate usage of 'that is'

Tags: phrase-meaning

In this page:
https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/11/google-photos-kills-off-unlimited-storage-policy-moving-forward/

the caption under Figure 1 is:

> Google is no longer offering unlimited photo storage—except to Pixel
> users, that is.

Why is it necessary to use "that is" at the end?

Does it add any extra information to the preceding sentence?

Answer (score 0):

> Google is no longer offering unlimited photo storage—except to Pixel users, that is.

That is adds quite a lot of information. The writer is annoyed with Google and "that is" clarifies that the writer is being satirical and ironic.

Paraphrased, the sentence might read:

That Google is no longer offering unlimited photo storage—except to Pixel users, comes as no great surprise, does it? Google is attempting to control a market that it already dominates. Because Google owns the Pixel brand, it is favouring its own customers so as not to cause a lot of trouble and also to encourage people to buy Pixel phones. This practice is discriminatory as well as being massively inconvenient to the majority of people who do not have a Pixel phone and do not want one. In fact, it is a clear demonstration that Google is attempting, by its power and this imposition to create a monopoly in the marketplace.

Comment: Yes, we used to hear about companies and corporations that were "Too big to be allowed to fail" We seem to have entered the time of companies and corporations that are "too big to be regulated"